# Transforming integrals of the form $\int \frac{f(x)}{\int g(x,y)dy}dx$ into multiple integration. Possible?

Tags: definite-integrals, numerical-methods

I'm currently dealing with integrals of this form, which I approximate numerically. I wonder if I can manage to perform some transformation resulting in a double integral or any other kind of multiple integral not on this rational form.

Thank you.

Edit: the $g$s I'm interested in are cumbersome functions. Suppose there aren't generally valid identities available. In this case, let's assume the numerical approximation for $\int f(x)dx$ can be written in the form $\sum_{i=1}^N w_i f(x_i)$, where $w_i$ $x_i$ are appropriate weights and abscissae, respectively. The integrals I need to approximate would then be ultimately written as the quotient of two sums. That should open for the possibility of other kinds of manipulations that I'd still be interested in.

Comment: You might want to be a little more specific. I don't believe there's any such identity that works in general, but there may very well be one for the particular $g$s you care about...

Comment: @Micah: I added some additional information to my post.

Comment: The answer to your question (after your edit) is a clear no.